# Automatic encoding of the Dynamic Segment in Farsi language in next13

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am recently migrating from ***next12***  to ***next 13***

I have a param  Dynamic Segment it as follows

```
const page = async ({ params }) => {

    const { slug } = params
    let RunnableLayout = null
    try {
        const { Layout: TempLayout } = await import('PostParts').catch(reason => console.error(reason)) || {}
        RunnableLayout = TempLayout
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }

    const data = await get(`/blogPost/data?slug=${slug}`)

    return RunnableLayout ?
        <RunnableLayout {...data} />
        :
        <Layout {...data} />

}

export default page
```

I noticed that The value of the parameter ***Slug*** in Farsi language is Encode

This item did not exist in next 12 and I did it manually Encoding

```
encodeURI(slug)
```

Is it possible to disable this item in next 13 ?
Because I am facing problems in supporting several languages